# Combine two different chart types in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Is it possible to combine a scatter chart and a line chart in the same picture?

From the example below i want to show the red part as a scatter plot, but the blue points should remain as connected by a line.
Is it also possible to choose which one is in the foreground and which one in the background?

Any help would be very appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today the Kusto Web Explorer does not support combining two chart types in the same visualization and does not support a way to configure z-index of the different series